# Getting specific properties from a class

Tags: c#

I have a class like so:

```
Public class Person 
{
    [NameInLib("id")]
    [NameInXML("ID")]
    public string Id;
    [NameInLib("empType")]
    [NameInXML("EmpType")]
    public string EmpType;
}
```

I have created these two classes for the attributes:

```
public class NameInLib : Attribute
{
    private string name;

    public string Description { get { return name; } }

    public NameInLib(string n)
    {
        this.name  = n;
    }
}

public class NameInXML : Attribute
{
    private string name;

    public string Description { get { return name; } }

    public NameInXML(string n)
    {
        this.name = n;
    }
}
```

There is an XML like so:

```
<Person>
 <Name insert = "false">ID</Name>
 <Name insert = "false">EmpType</Name>
<Person>
```

from this XML I will get the tags whose insert attribute is true.

The attributes can be obtained and simple for loop can do the comaprison with those from the xml.

I want to know if there is a better way to get the NameInLib attrbute from the Person class of only those properties which exists in the list obtained from the XML.

Comment: A better way than ... what? You didn't show any code.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand the question. Can you put it in different wording?

Comment: I am trying to create the Person object and set only those properties which are true in the xml. This person object is similar to another object which has different property names. The attribute NameInLib is to get those properties.